# String literal VT100 representation to unicode

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

How can I convert the following string literal:

```
token = "\x1b(0l\x1b(BHeader"
```

Into:

```
"┌Header"
```

I am receiving literal Unix box-drawing characters from a library and need to convert to unicode for unit testing.

Comment: I've never heard of "literal Unix box drawing characters". Do you have a reference for what this is? In the string you show, I see the ESC control character (`U+1B`) and a few common ASCII characters (`(`, `0`, `1`, and `B`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the VT-100 alternate character set (something that was less obvious before the question topic was edited). The sequence `esc ( 0` changes the encoding to the alternate set, and the sequence `esc ( B` changes it back. There are only a handful of such characters mapped. Here is the mapping.

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   A   B   C   D   E   F
6                                           ┘   ┐   ┌   └   ┼   
7       ─           ├   ┤   ┴   ┬   │
```

To do the conversion you're going to have to set up a dict that maps these codes to the corresponding Unicode codepoints and convert it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

@BoarGules was correct. Here is my solution to decode strings like this:

```
vt_100_mapping = {
    '0x71': '─',
    '0x74': '├',
    '0x75': '┤',
    '0x76': '┴',
    '0x77': '┬',
    '0x78': '│',
    '0x6a': '┘',
    '0x6b': '┐',
    '0x6c': '┌',
    '0x6d': '└',
    '0x6e': '┼',
}
```

---

```
from itertools import groupby

def decode_vt_100(iterable, default_set='(B', alt_set='(0'):
    for is_escape, group in groupby(iterable, lambda _: _ =='\x1b'):
        if is_escape:
            continue

        characters = ''.join(group)

        if characters.startswith(default_set):
            yield characters[len(default_set):]

        elif characters.startswith(alt_set):
            for character in characters[len(alt_set):]:
                yield vt_100_mapping[hex(ord(character))]
```

---

```
>>> print(''.join(decode_vt_100("\x1b(0l\x1b(BHeader")))
┌Header
```